# MongoDB: sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, nosql

Consider the following MongoDB document:

```
SomeObject {
    nested_objects_ids : [
        ObjectId( "1..." ), 
        ObjectId( "2..." ),
        ...
        ObjectId( "N..." )
    ]
}
```

The length of `nested_object_ids` is not limited.
Is there an elegant way to keep the `nested_object_ids` array sorted after pushing arbitrary values (i.e. ObjectIds)?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you sorting by? `ObjectId` itself? If you want them sorted by insertion order that should already happen.

Comment: +1 for the question because I'd also like to know if there is a good solution.  As far as I know, if you want them in a numerical sort order, you'd actually need to write back ($set) the entire array in a sorted form rather than simply using $push : anObjectId

Comment: @Russel, for example, first an object with _id "45..." is inserted, the next object has _id = "42...". It will be inserted to the end of the array, but I'd like to have it right before the object with id="45...".

Comment: I think what I'm getting at it why are you using ObjectIds for sorting? They won't sort into any meaningful order. If you're overriding with a custom value for the _id field such as an incrementing int you lose a lot of the benefits of an ObjectId so I would consider revisiting your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an elegant way to keep the `nested_object_ids` array sorted after pushing arbitrary values?

Unfortunately, there is nothing I would consider "elegant".

The `$push` command does not work here. Your only option is to pull the entire sub-array into the client and then re-write it with a `$set`.

Honestly, when it comes to dealing with "arrays of objects", MongoDB has limited functionality. You can update with `$push`, `$pull` and you can index on an object field, but that's about it.

It's difficult to update a specific sub-object. And querying doesn't return the sub-object, but instead returns the whole document. You could filter it down to returning `nested_object_ids`, but you always get the whole set there.

A question for you: **why do the nested objects need to be sorted**?

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. Consider the situation where ObjectIds kept in this array would come from different non-synchronized sources, so that e.g. ObjectId_n < ObjectId_(n - 1). And you'd like to keep those sorted, because there are hundreds of such entries in the array, and it takes time to sort it every time a new ObjectId is added. I was hoping that there is a way to "tell" MongoDB to keep a particular array in e.g. binary tree :) Maybe someday...

Answer (score 2):

You can now do this with the $push to sorted array feature: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8008

Comment: I'd like to add that [SERVER-991](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-991) documentation provides more information on `$sort` within `$push`.

Comment: It looks like you can use `$orderBy` from that feature request... But I am running mongo through meteor (so mongo 2.6) and it doesn't look like I can do this...?

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming 2.4 release of Mongodb will allow for sorted $push.